How to get the host name in Zig
I am very new to Zig, and I want to get the host name of my machine. There was a std.os.gethostname() function in Zig, but it's gone now (currently using v0.12).
There's a std.c.gethostname() function, but it's not standard and I have to link with libc.

Try with std.posix.gethostname

You can use std.posix.gethostname. As per this Issue/PR[rename std.os to std.posix] the API is now lives under std.posix namespace.

I finally found the std.posix.gethostname() function! Seems like everything from the std.os has been moved to std.posix (or others maybe had been moved to somewhere else).

Not everything, only the stuff which was in the POSIX standard. std.os is still there for OS-specific things.
